# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error while accessing via Node module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on Laravel application and trying to access `jQuery` via `nodemodules`

Here is my **app.js** file:

```
var $ = require('../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery')
//require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min')
require('./site')
```

The resulting file it generates is given [here](http://pastebin.com/SuwFSfxV)

Comment: what module loader are you using and you used `npm` to install jquery? Have you tried `var $ = require('jquery')`?

Comment: @Craicerjack I had to pass entire path as I am using it in Laravel. Ye I installed via `npm`. I am using `browsify` to use `require` in my file

Comment: Have you used `elixir` for interaction with these files - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#browserify - seems Laravel has its own `API` for helping to deal with this stuff.

Comment: Yes I am using Elexir

Comment: **This task assumes that your scripts are stored in resources/assets/js and will place the resulting file in public/js/main.js. You may pass a custom output location as an optional second argument:** I think then, having elixir configured you should be able to just `require('jquery')` without the absolute file path

Comment: On a side note it might be better to use a package manager specifically designed for front-end that installs packages in an easier location - like bower. - elixir and bower - https://laravel-news.com/2014/10/setting-laravel-elixr-bootstrap/

Comment: Have you set the path for `jquery` in your `gulpfile`?

Comment: @Craicerjack `gulp` calling app.js which itself includes jQuery. Check original question

Comment: try in your gulp:         `var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var paths = {
    'jquery': '../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
}` and then `require('jquery');`

Comment: @Craicerjack Same `app.js:10087 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error

Answer (score 1):

Define `$` globally, like this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```